# Android : Custom Checksum Calculation

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate custom checksum calculation in java.help me out . how to do the below example operation ?

example :

```
data : 30313037303130453030

hex summation :
x = ' 30+31+30+37+30+31+30+45+30+30' = '1FE'

Not of hex value :
y = NOT(x) = 01

Answer : Checksum = 3031
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a nice tut about the cksum calculation (it's in java) - [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/ChecksumByteArray.shtml). Here's also a `.jar` that can be helpful - [here](https://pacer.ischool.utexas.edu/bitstream/2081/9004/3/JacksumDocumentation.htm). There's even a class Checksum, which can be found here - [LINK](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/Checksum.html).

To obtain the "cksum" that you're talking about (because it is really a fake "cksum" that you're creating and can really cause you some problems if you rely on the uniqueness of it among the same strings representing different files etc.) you can use this:

```
int value = 0;
String incHex = "";

for (int i = 0; i == data.length(); i+=2){
  valueInt += Integer.parseInt(hex, data.substring(i, i+2));
}
resultHex = Integer.toHexString(valueInt);
```

This `resultHex` is the "x" from your example, the `valueInt` is the decimal representation of that numer (the sum of all the parts of the data string).

Comment: thanks for the links, but i want to perform custom operation as above example in java...???

Comment: Then, you'll have to explain what is this `data` stream (is it a file, a string, what it is, byte array, hex array).

Comment: data is a string format (hex values), from that string it should pick two-two bits and do hex summation and final sum has to be NOT (SUM) ...

Comment: You can do the following -> Sum the "bits" as hex values (what I mean is that you should conver those into decimal). You're now summing decimals, not hex values in your example. Converts every of the "bits" to decimal first, then perform the sum, afterwards convert them to hex again ! This hex number, when converted to decimal, will give you a **fake** cksum, because this number can be a filesize, which can be the same for two files, even though they are different.

Comment: is there any function to do hex summation: example from data: 0x30+0x31+0x30+0x37+0x30+0x31+0x30+0x45+0x30+0x30 =1FE and NOT (1FE) = 01